# How we can write an array with some subscript written in alphabets like

Tags: tables, matrices, subscripts

[image]
The image has a problem which i wanna resolve if you solve my problem, i am just a beginner so

Comment: You mention "array with some subscript" in the title of your posting, but I'm not sure which part of the equations in the screenshot you posted you're trying to replicate. Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me if I've understood your typesetting objective(s) correctly. I will assume that you're looking for methods for typesetting multi-letter variables, some of which may be placed in a subscript position.

If this assumption is correct, you may achieve your objective by using `\mathit` to typeset the names of multi-letter variables, i.e., by placing the names in `\mathit` (or, depending on your font setup, `\textit`) wrappers.

Observe that this will also lead the variable names to be typeset more compactly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}}   % macro for typesetting variable names
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional: Times Roman text and math fonts

\begin{document}
$
\left(\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \vn{mass}_{\vn{in}} \\
  \vn{rate}
\end{array}\right)
= \vn{density} \times \vn{velocity} \times \vn{area}
$

\medskip
$\vn{density}$, $\vn{velocity}$, $\vn{area}$ vs.

$density$, $velocity$, $area$
\end{document}
```

Aside: If you're willing to load the [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools) package, you could replace `\left(\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}` and `\end{array}\right)` with `\begin{pmatrix*}[l]` and `\end{pmatrix*}`, respectively.

Comment: thanks, this resolve my issue